# Azure Data warehouse and SSRS support

Tags: azure, reporting-services, data-warehouse

Could anyone please confirm if I can use SSRS along with ADW?

If Yes any caveats or Version's I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Azure SQL Data Warehouse supports all SSRS versions.